# Unable to check if username exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to Stackoverflow and I am just starting to work with .NET Core and my first time using identity. I basically was using an ajax call to a controller to see if a username already existed. Then I did some research and found that I can use RemoteAttribute below is my RegisterViewModel.

```
    public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "some error", MinimumLength = 2)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    [RegularExpression(@"(^[\w]+$)", ErrorMessage = "some error")]
    [Remote("CheckUserName", "Account", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "some error")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
```

Then in my controller I have this.

```
    public async Task<JsonResult> CheckUserName(string username)
    {
        var user = db.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == username).FirstOrDefault();
        if (user == null)
            return Json(true);
        else
            return Json(false);    
    }
```

but my datacontext is always throwing *Object Reference not set to an instance of an object*, So I used *FindByNameAsync* Identity methods which always return null, see below.

```
    public async Task<JsonResult> CheckUserName(string username)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
        //but user is always null ??
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `string username` needs to be `string Username`?

Comment: Are you saying the value of the parameter `username` is `null`? If so, show you view code for generating the form control.

Comment: @StephenMuecke No the value returned from FindByNameAsync is null,
so `user`

Comment: Then that suggests there is no record in the db matching `username`

Comment: @StephenMuecke but there is a record in the db that's the thing. I feel like it as something to do with _userManager and not being able to access the records or something.

Comment: `Object Reference not set to an instance of an object` you are missing the important point here. What exactly is `null`? `db` or `db.Users`? That could be only one of these 2 objects because `FirstOrDefault()` won't throw an exception if the collection is empty. It will simply return `null` as you already know judging by your code. So obviously you have a problem with your database, not with the way you are searching the user. Also pay attention that `==` won't match if by mistake you have a space that you didn't see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what I did but it seems to be working now.
I added

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
```

attribute above the method, that might have done it. But that wasn't there it should have thrown a 401 error. Either way thanks for everyone help.